# I'm trying to make a relationship for category and product table, the table is shop_categories_products

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

the shop_categories_products table has 2 field, product_id and category_id.

relation to category on my product model

```
public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Modules\Shop\App\Models\Category', 'shop_categories_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

and relation to product on my category model

```
public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Modules\Shop\App\Models\Product', 'shop_categories_products', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

this is insertData method on my ProductRepository

```
public function insertData($request) {
        $product = new Product();
        $inventory = new ProductInventory();

        $product->categories->product_id = $product->id;
        $product->categories->category_id = $request->category;
        dd($product);
        $product->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $product->sku = $request->sku;
        $product->type = "SIMPLE";
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->sale_price = $request->sale_price;
        $product->status = "ACTIVE";
        $product->stock_status = $request->stock_status;
        $product->manage_stock = 1;
        $product->featured_image = $request->foto;
        $product->publish_date = now();
        $product->save();

        $inventory->qty = $request->stock;
        $inventory->product_id = $product->id;
        $inventory->save();
    }
```

this line code returns null

```
$product->categories->product_id = $product->id;
```

but this code can get the id of the product

```
$inventory->product_id = $product->id;
```

requested data are successfully inserted to products table, but the relationship are failed

Answer (score 0):

For insertion on relation you need to save your data.

In your case add this line `$product->categories->save();`

```
$product->categories->product_id = $product->id;
$product->categories->category_id = $request->category;
$product->categories->save();
```